# how to make json value from hive columns

Tags: hive

I want to convert hive columns to json value.

I know how to convert json value to string i.e. by using `get_json_object`.

For example, this is the hive table:

```
id  |   name 
-------------
1   |  kim   
2   |  lee   
3   |  park
```

Expected Output is:

```
[ {"1" : "kim"}, {"2" : "lee"}, {"3" : "park"} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Brickhouse UDF](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) `collect`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

SELECT collect(map(CAST(id as STRING), name)) from table;
```